# Issue with selfdestruct() getting an error

Tags: solidity, truffle, error, selfdestruct

main contract function which calls my secondary contract

```
 function gameOver(uint _matchId)public payable onlyOwner returns(bool) {
    Match my_match = Match(matchTracker[_matchId]);
    bool success = my_match.destroy(msg.sender);
    if(success == true)
        delete matchTracker[_matchId];
    return success;

  }
```

here matchTracker stores the Address of each of the Match contracts

Match contract destroy function

```
function destroy (address payable _owner)external returns(bool)
        {   require(_owner == owner);
            selfdestruct(owner);
            return true;
        }
```

Can anyone identify what is wrong?
solidity version in use is 0.5.13

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it at compile time or during call execution? How are Match contracts created? Who is the owner of Match contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selfdestruct requires a parameter of type `address payable`.

What is the type of `owner` in your code.?  If you're using the OpenZeppelin `Ownable.sol`, it's not `payable`.

You could cast it, but since you've already `require`d that `_owner` is equal to `owner`, and the former *is* `payable` you should simply be able to write

`selfdestruct(_owner);`

instead.

Comment: my owner is indeed address payable

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: i removed the return from the destroy function and now its working fine..not sure what the issue was though

Comment: well, I can't find it explicitly mentioned anywhere, but I think that `selfdestruct` stops execution of the contract immediately - so your `return true` will not get called.  The return value will either be undefined or `0` (ie `false`)

You don't really need it to return a `bool` in your example, as it can't fail.  The `require` will abort the transaction as a whole if it's triggered